# arraylist method to show all accounts doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Well im trying to change an array to arraylist, the create account seems to be working but the "show accounts" method keeps returning me that there's not account register.
this is the add account method (the commentary's are the original array)

```
    //Metodo para agregar Cuentas
    public void agregarCuenta(Cuenta c){
    ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();
    cuentas.add(c);

    /*
    Cuenta aux[] = new Cuenta[cuentas.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(cuentas, 0, aux, 0, cuentas.length);
    aux[aux.length-1] = c;
    cuentas = aux;
    */

}
```

and this is the show accounts method

```
public static void mostrarAhorro()
    {
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();
        //Si no hay cuentas en el arreglo, nos muestra el siguiente error
        if (cuentas.size() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No hay cuentas registradas.");
            return;
        }



        System.out.println("****Lista de cuentas de ahorro****");
        //For  para mostrar todas las cuentas de ahorro
        for (int i = 0; i<cuentas.size();i++) {

            if (cuentas.get(i) instanceof CuentaAhorros)
            {

                System.out.println("Id de cuenta: " + (i+1) +"\n"+ cuentas);
            }


        }

    }
```

this is the rest of the code

```
package Programas;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Banco.Cuenta;

import Banco.CuentaAhorros;

import Banco.CuentaCheques;

import Banco.Movimientos;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class programa1 {

//Instanciar scanner y formato de moneda
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static DecimalFormat MONEDA = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");;   

//Arreglo de clases instanciada.
//private static Cuenta[] cuentas = new Cuenta[0];
//private static Movimientos [] movimientos = new Movimientos[0];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //ArrayList cuentas = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();
    ArrayList<Movimientos> movimientos = new ArrayList<Movimientos>();






    //Selec para mantener el while corriendo, y while para mantener el menu.
    int selec = 0;
    while (selec <7)
    {

        //Imprimir lista de opciones
        System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: "+ "\n1.-Crear cuenta de ahorros."+ "\n2.-Crear cuenta de cheques."+ "\n3.-Mostrar listado de cuentas de ahorro."+ "\n4.-Mostrar listado de cuentas de cheques."+ "\n5.-Mostrar listado de todas las cuentas."+ "\n6.-Operaciones de una cuenta."+ "\n7.-Salir");

        //Pedirle al usuario una opcion
        selec = sc.nextInt();

        //Switch para que cuando selec cambie se ejecute una opcion.
        switch (selec)
        {

            //Caso 1 para agregar Cuenta de ahorros
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Ha escogido crear una cuenta de ahorros."+ "\nIngrese el saldo inicial, y la tasa de interes: ");

                //Instancia de Cuenta tipo ahorros
                Cuenta c1 = new CuentaAhorros(sc.nextDouble(),sc.nextDouble());

                cuentas.add(c1);
                System.out.println("\nCuenta de ahorros agregada exitosamente."+ "\nTotal de cuentas: " + cuentas.size() + "\nfecha de ingreso: " + movimientos.size());
                break;

            //Caso 2 para agregar cuenta de ahorros.    
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ha escogido crear una cuenta de cheques."+ "\nIngrese el saldo inicial, y el costo de manejo de la cuenta: ");

                //Instancia de cuenta tipo cheques
                Cuenta c2 = new CuentaCheques(sc.nextDouble(),sc.nextDouble());

                cuentas.add(c2);
                System.out.println("\nCuenta de cheques agregada exitosamente."+ "\nTotal de cuentas: "+ cuentas.size());
                break;

            //Caso para mostrar la lista de cuentas de ahorro    
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Listado de cuentas de ahorro: ");
                mostrarAhorro();
                break;

            //Caso para mostrar la lista de cuentas de cheques    
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Listado de cuentas de Cheques: ");
                mostrarCheques();
                break;

            //Caso para mostrar todas las cuentas    
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Listado de todas las cuentas: ");
                mostrarCuentas();
                break;

            //Caso para realizar operaciones de una cuenta
            case 6:
            operacionesCuenta();
            break;
        }


    }


}






//Metodo para agregar Cuentas
    public void agregarCuenta(Cuenta c){
    ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();
    cuentas.add(c);


    //cuentas = aux;

    /*
    Cuenta aux[] = new Cuenta[cuentas.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(cuentas, 0, aux, 0, cuentas.length);
    aux[aux.length-1] = c;
    cuentas = aux;
    */

}

    //Metodo para mostrar las cuentas de tipo ahorro
    public static void mostrarAhorro()
    {
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
        //Si no hay cuentas en el arreglo, nos muestra el siguiente error
        if (cuentas.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("No hay cuentas registradas.");
            return;
        }



        System.out.println("****Lista de cuentas de ahorro****");
        //For  para mostrar todas las cuentas de ahorro
        for (int i = 0; i<cuentas.size();i++) {

            if (cuentas.get(i) instanceof CuentaAhorros)
            {
                System.out.println("Id de cuenta: " + (i+1) +"\n"+ cuentas);
            }


        }

    }


    //Metodo para cuenta cheques

    public static void mostrarCheques()
    {

        //Si no hay cuentas en el arreglo, nos muestra el siguiente error
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cuentas.size() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No hay cuentas registradas.");
            return;
        }



        System.out.println("****Lista de cuentas de Cheques****");
        //For  para mostrar todas las cuentas de ahorro
        for (int i = 0; i<cuentas.size();i++) {

            if (cuentas.get(i) instanceof CuentaCheques)
            {
                //CuentaCheques a = (CuentaCheques)cuentas.get(1);
                //System.out.println("Id de cuenta: " + (i+1) +"\n"+ a);
                System.out.println(cuentas);
            }


        }

    }


    public static void mostrarCuentas()
    {

        //Si no hay cuentas en el arreglo, nos muestra el siguiente error
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cuentas.size() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No hay cuentas registradas.");
            return;
        }



        System.out.println("****Lista de todas las cuentas****");
        //For  para mostrar todas las cuentas de ahorro
        for (int i = 0; i<cuentas.size();i++) {

            if (cuentas.get(i) instanceof CuentaCheques)
            {
                CuentaCheques a = (CuentaCheques)cuentas.get(i);
                System.out.println("Tipo de cuenta: Cheques. "+ "\nId de cuenta: " + (i+1) +"\n"+ a.toString());
            }

            else
            {
                CuentaAhorros a = (CuentaAhorros)cuentas.get(i);
                System.out.println("Tipo de cuenta: Ahorro."+ "\nId de cuenta: "+ (i+1) +"\n"+ a.toString());
            }

        }

    }


    public static void operacionesCuenta()
    {

        System.out.println("Seleccione la Id de la cuenta que desea usar: ");
        int id = (sc.nextInt() -1);
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();

        if(id > cuentas.size())
        {
            System.out.println("Escogio una cuenta que no existe.");
            return;
        }




        if(cuentas.get(id) instanceof CuentaCheques)
        {
            int choice = 0;

            while(choice<6)
            {
                CuentaCheques a = (CuentaCheques)cuentas.get(id);
                System.out.println("Selecciono cuenta de cheques."+ "\n1.-Consultar Saldo."+ "\n2.-Retirar."+ "\n3.-Depositar." + "\n4.-Aplicar manejo de cuenta."+ "\n5.-Ver informacion de la cuenta."+ "\n6.-Salir."+ "\nSeleccione una opcion:");

                choice = sc.nextInt();

                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("\nEl saldo actual de la cuenta es: " +MONEDA.format(a.getSaldo()));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("\nIngrese la cantidad que desea retirar: ");
                        double retirarAhorros = sc.nextDouble();
                        a.retirar(retirarAhorros);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("\nIngrese la cantidad que desea depositar: ");
                        double depositarAhorros = sc.nextDouble();
                        a.depositar(depositarAhorros);
                        break;

                    case 4:

                        System.out.println("Selecciono aplicar manejo de la cuenta.");
                        a.aplicarCostoManejoCuenta();
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Selecciono ver informacion de la cuenta.");
                        System.out.println(a);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        else
        {
            int choice2 = 0;

            while(choice2<6)
            {
                CuentaAhorros a = (CuentaAhorros)cuentas.get(id);
                System.out.println("Escogio cuenta de ahorros."+ "\n1.-Consultar Saldo."+ "\n2.-Retirar."+ "\n3.-Depositar."+ "\n4.-Aplicar manejo de cuenta."+ "\n5.-Ver informacion de la cuenta."+ "\n6.-Salir."+ "\nSeleccione una opcion:");

                choice2 = sc.nextInt();

                switch(choice2)
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("\nEl saldo actual de la cuenta es: " +MONEDA.format(a.getSaldo()));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("\nIngrese la cantidad que desea retirar: ");
                        double retirarCheques = sc.nextDouble();
                        a.retirar(retirarCheques);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("\nIngrese la cantidad que desea depositar: ");
                        double depositarCheques = sc.nextDouble();
                        a.depositar(depositarCheques);
                        break;

                    case 4:

                        System.out.println("Selecciono aplicar manejo de la cuenta.");
                        a.aplicarInteres();
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Selecciono ver informacion de la cuenta.");
                        System.out.println(a);
                        break;
                }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you create a new `ArrayList` each time?

Comment: Well beacuse it appears the follow error "cannot find symbol class".

Comment: You will need to import the class, it's not part of the core `lang` package - `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: now i see it, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, every time you call the mostrarAhorro method, and even every time you call the agregarCuenta method, you are overwriting the cuentas array list with:

```
ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();
```

Every time you call this, it creates an empty array and ignores any data it previously had.

You  only need to create it once and store it as a member variable in the class.

```
ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();

   //Metodo para agregar Cuentas
public void agregarCuenta(Cuenta c){
    cuentas.add(c);

/*
Cuenta aux[] = new Cuenta[cuentas.length+1];
System.arraycopy(cuentas, 0, aux, 0, cuentas.length);
aux[aux.length-1] = c;
cuentas = aux;
*/

}

public static void mostrarAhorro()
{
    //Si no hay cuentas en el arreglo, nos muestra el siguiente error
    if (cuentas.size() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("No hay cuentas registradas.");
        return;
    }



    System.out.println("****Lista de cuentas de ahorro****");
    //For  para mostrar todas las cuentas de ahorro
    for (int i = 0; i<cuentas.size();i++) {

        if (cuentas.get(i) instanceof CuentaAhorros)
        {

            System.out.println("Id de cuenta: " + (i+1) +"\n"+ cuentas);
        }


    }

}
```

EDIT:  You need to declare the cuentas array at the top of your class so all methods have access to it.  Delete the creation of cuentas in the main method as well.

```
public class programa1 {

//Instanciar scanner y formato de moneda
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static DecimalFormat MONEDA = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
private ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();   

//Arreglo de clases instanciada.
//private static Cuenta[] cuentas = new Cuenta[0];
//private static Movimientos [] movimientos = new Movimientos[0];

public static void main(String[] args) {
//ArrayList cuentas = new ArrayList(); 

ArrayList<Movimientos> movimientos = new ArrayList<Movimientos>();
```

Comment: but when i do that appears the follow error "cannot find symbol class" 
i have put the arraylist like this
"ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();" 
after the "public static void main"

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing the rest of your code.  You will probably see that error if your methods are in multiple classes.

Comment: See my edit.  You only need to declare it once at the top of the class.  If this answers you question please mark my answer as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a complete new instance of the arrayList in the display method.

[image]

If this list is common across the current run , you can just declare it as

**private static List cuentaList = new ArrayList();**